# how to solve the problem while apduting python3 on linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, upgrade, updates

I have python 3.5.3
I m trying to upgrade to python 3.7.2
I used the cammand bellow :

```
 sudo apt install python3.7.2
```

I got the following message

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7.2'
```

I used the command below to fix it

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7.2
```

and I till have the same problem

Comment: is this even how to download python, shouldn't You like go to the https://www.python.org/downloads/ website and download from there? since if You just call to install some stuff obviously it won't search the whole internet to find that package

Comment: @Matiiss is this possible in lunix ???

Comment: I don't know, I have windows, but the website seems to provide some files for linux too

Comment: No ,I tink the only way to install python in linux is through the terminal

Comment: still, try downloading those files (there are some kind of tarballs) and then doing sth, maybe there is also a yt tutorial or a website that has a tutorial on how to get python on linux, also maybe try a different version(s)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Internet by searching your first error message.

Hello,

Have you tried running `python3.7 --version` instead of only `python3`?

If this still does not work what I would suggest is following these steps here:

Run a quick update and install the following package:
`apt update`
`sudo apt install software-properties-common`
Add the following to your source list:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
Note: In case that you get prompted just press Enter to continue
After that install Python 3.7 with the command that you’ve specified in your question:
`sudo apt install python3.7`

Then again test this with:
`python3.7 --version`

Hope that this helps!

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-install-pyhton-3-7-version-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-couldn-t-find-any-package-by-regex-python3-7

Comment: Sorry it's pretty much the same as you tried.

Comment: thank you but , it is still the same error message